# Mock super().__init__

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest

I have a parent class that, within its `__init__` calls some internal class methods:

```
class Parent:
  def __init__(self):
    ...
    my_method()

  def my_method(self, a...):
     pass
```

Afterwards, I create a child class that relies on that Parent class. After creating instance objects of the Child class, they explicitly invoque the parent's `__init__` method

```
class Child(Parent):
  def __init__(self, a):
    super().__init__(a)
```

I would like to mock the parent class such that I can test its child without fully relying on the parent's initialization function, which calls `my_method`. This `my_method` is problematic and causes the test of the Child to fail due to its parent necessarily calling that method.

Answers with pytest would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to prevent the parent class from calling `my_method` during initialization, would be to pass an extra argument to the `__init__` function of the parent that specifies whether the method should be called.

```py
class Parent:
  def __init__(self, call_method=True):
    ...

    if call_method:
        my_method()

  def my_method(self, a...):
     pass
```

And then in the child class:

```py
class Child(Parent):
  def __init__(self, a, call_method=True):
    super().__init__(call_method)
```

When instantiating Child classes during testing, simply set `call_method` to false.

```py
child = Child(call_method=False)
```